# Why are pagination links not displaying on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, navigation

I was trying to fix the width of the images however, unexpectedly, the navigation pager below disappeared.(pages 1,2,3). I am new to CSS and have no idea what happened. I don't now how to fix this, the navigation codes are still present however I guess it cannot find any space to show up. Can you help?

Code:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3704b07a027426208738
Website:https://www.alphabitrage.com

Comment: I'm looking at your page and I see the wide images. How wide do you want them? What's the `id` or `class` of the navigation?

Comment: Dont expect people to go onto links, rather just put the code here or better create a fiddle and explain what is the problem and what do you want to acheive

Comment: @Michael_B I just wanted to make site not fall apart when zoomed out. Especially, I had difficulties in footer. But when I am manipulated the code, the pager disappeared.

Comment: @TheUknown Sİnce I am newbie, I had no idea which part to extract. Sorry.

Comment: I see lots of code with "pager" in it. Which `div` of `class` or `id` contains the pager you're referring to?

Comment: @Michael_B I think it starts with <!--Page Navigation Starts-->

Comment: This code is very extensive and convoluted. Not easy to follow ;-)

Comment: Yes Sorry I just adapted from a template

Comment: No problem. What was the code section you changed before the pager disappeared?

Comment: I am not sure but I make 100% some widths and I suspect it is outer-footer.

Comment: Was this code ever working well for you? I ask because the source code (from the GitHub link you provided) is absolutely filled with errors. Just going through the code myself I lost count after 50. But there are many, many more errors. So I'm wondering if this was working for you before the pager disappeared.

Comment: Yes , at least that is what I think, I pasted this into blogger html and it worked.The website I mentined is the final product. But I am sure there are some errors.

Comment: Just ran the code through [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org): **565 code errors**

Comment: I will try to debug it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86565/discussion-between-michael-b-and-nily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your code until I counted about 50 coding errors.

So I ran the source code (from the GitHub link you provided) through the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/), which found 565 coding errors.

This alone suggests multiple problems with your web page and potential difficulties ahead in terms of maintenance and troubleshooting.

However, I understand you're working with a template so recommending that you re-structure your code to be valid and semantically correct (which I would normally do) may not be feasible in this case.

Also, you mention in your comments that the code was working well until you made some adjustments to the widths of images. So I put the errors aside and continued searching for a possible problem.

Providing a link to another website with a working template was a good idea on your part. I was able to compare your code with the code from the other site.

I discovered that your code was missing the divs that render the HTML for the pagination links.

In particular:

```
<div class="blog-pager" id="blog-pager"></div>
```

... is completely missing from your code.

### Your Site

[image]

### Other Site

[image]

Once you restore that code block your pager should re-appear.

Comment: Obviously this is the problem. I will troubleshoot in that way. Thanks.